# Laplace Transform of $\frac{\psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)}{x^{3/2}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

Is there a closed form expression for the Laplace Transform of the following expression?

$$f(x)=\frac{\psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)}{x^{3/2}}$$

where $\psi^{(k)}$ is the [polygamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) function.

$f(x)$ [arises](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286847/217) when sampling numbers $1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\ldots$ with relative frequencies $1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\ldots$, and treating this distribution as continuous. $f(x)$ is the probability density function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an explicit expression, but a useful asymptotic expansion for large $z$ may be obtained using [$(5.15.9)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.15.E9) and [Watson's lemma](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.4.i):
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - zt} t^{ - 3/2} \psi ^{(2)} (t^{ - 1/2} )\,{\rm d}t} 
& \sim  - \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - zt} t^{ - 3/2} \bigg( {t + t^{3/2}  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {(2k + 1)B_{2k} t^{k + 1} } } \bigg){\rm d}t} 
\\ & \sim  - \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{z}}  - \frac{1}{z} - 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\Gamma\! \left( {k + \frac{3}{2}} \right)\!B_{2k} }}{{z^{k + 1/2} }}} ,
\end{align*}
as $z\to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\le \frac{\pi}{2}-\delta< \frac{\pi}{2}$. The sector of validity may be enlarged and explicit error bounds can be given if necessary.